# Visual studio/asp.net ignoring my javascript changes and creating a [dynamic] js file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to learn asp.net and javascript following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs).

I have it working fine but wanted to experiment and try different things, I noticed that whenever I change quiz-controller.cs visual studio seems to ignore my changes and when I run the app it creates a new tab with 'quiz-controller.js [dynamic]' in the title.

This happens only when I change the quiz-controller.js file, the rest of the project and code is straight out of the tutorial, for example if I change line 16 to be '$scope.title = "testing"' and run the app with a breakpoint on the line visual studio creates a 'quiz-controller.js [dynamic]' tab and places the breakpoint there, with my changes reverted.